# "parameter has incomplete type" warning

Tags: c, incomplete-type

I have this in a C file:

```
struct T
{
    int foo;
};
```

the C file has an include to an h file with those lines:

```
typedef struct T T;
void listInsertFirst(T data, int key, LinkedList* ListToInsertTo);
```

the function `listInsertFirst` is the one I'm getting the warning on.  How can I fix it?

Comment: thanks,and what if I want the type to be knonwn if someone includes the h file ?

Comment: One thing you should be aware of is that you're passing a `struct` *by value* here. That's almost surely a bad idea...

Comment: Any reason why you are typedef-ing in the C file rather than in the header file. Also, you can typedef the struct straight out by having something like struct T { int foo;} T;

Comment: What parameter is the compiler referring to?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what is the right thing to do when implementing (any dictionary like) DS:should the person that called the insert function do the memory allocation and pass a pointer,or should he pass the object and the insert function should do the allocation ?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado  I'm not sure (it doesn't say) but I think that it's the T type parameter

Comment: @user: Well, if `struct T` is actually defined somewhere, then this should not be a problem.  Is the defintion of `struct T` in the file before you defined type `typedef struct T T;` or is it actually in a different file?  Or is it in a header that you didn't actually include?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado I moved the decleration to the header and it's ok now :)
but I'm still not sure about what I wrote in my previous comment to Gangadhar.thoughts ?

Comment: @user: To be honest, I can't say for sure.  There isn't enough information here to make a good suggestion.  I don't know how you've implemented things.  Though as that is a different problem now, you should ask about that in a new question (with much more information about your types).

Comment: @Gangadhar: "typedef struct { int foo; } T;" with your first T ("struct T {...") only needed if the struct needs to refer to itself, such as "typedef struct Node { struct Node *next; } Node;".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've found out in the comments, the problem was that the definition of `struct T` occurred after the definition of `T` in the header.  You really have things backwards here.  The header should be defining all the types and function prototypes and your C files should be using them.

What you want to be doing instead is change the signature of your insert function to receive a pointer to your data and the size of the data.  Then you can allocate some memory for the data, copy it and store it.  You don't need a specific type, just declare it a `void *`.

```
void listInsertFirst(void *data, size_t data_size, int key, LinkedList* ListToInsertTo);
```

Then the caller would do something like this:

```
struct T { int foo; };
struct T x = { ... };
int someKey = ...;
LinkedList *someList = ...;
listInsertFirst(&x, sizeof x, someKey, someList);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you include the header file, the compiler knows that `T` is a structure of unknown size and that `listInsertFirst` wants one as its first argument. But the compiler cannot arrange a call to `listInsertFirst` as it doesn't know how many bytes to push on the stack for the `T data` parameter, the size of `T` is only known inside the file where `listInsertFirst` is defined.

The best solution would be to change `listInsertFirst` to take a `T*` as its first argument so your header file would say this:

```
extern void listInsertFirst(T *data, int key, LinkedList* ListToInsertTo);
```

Then you get an opaque pointer for your `T` data type and, since all pointers are the same size (in the modern world at least), the compiler will know how to build the stack when calling `listInsertFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the first parameter that is the problem?  To be sure, try changing the parameter type from `T` to `int` temporarily.  More than likely, the third parameter is actually the problem.

Many compilers don't point at the problem in these sorts of issues very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the structure definition to the h file, before the typedef.

Comment: the problem with this is that I have :

typedef struct LinkedList
{
 ListNode* head;
 ListNode* tail;
}LinkedList;

which uses the type "ListNode",
If I put this typedef struct on the h file I'd have to add the typedef struct of "ListNode",but no one should be aware of this type...

Comment: But LinkedList must be aware of ListNode. So, if someone is aware of LinkedList, it must be aware also with ListNOde. You can also add another h file: Add ListNode to the new h file and include it in your original h file

Answer (score 0):

1. Define `struct T` in header, not in .c file;
2. Choose different names for structure and typedef.